# Ищу алгоритм для превращения картинки, состоящей из кривых линий в прямые линии

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение, компьютерное-зрение

Нужен какой-то алгоритм для превращения картинки, состоящей из всяких кривых линий в картинку, состоящую из прямых линий. Например, окружность должна превращаться в многоугольник, так, чтобы выглядело не очень плохо. В гугле нашел всего одну статью на английском, но там что-то сильно умное. Если есть алгоритмы попроще, то хотелось бы про них узнать. На крайний случай пойду разбираться с этой статьей

Comment: есть предложение: попытаться уменьшать размер изображения, до исчезновения округлостей, затем обработать уменьшеное фото. В этом случае круг будет преобразован в квадрат, возможно в восьмиугольник.

Comment: К сожалению, в этом вопросе требуется не сжатие изображения, а преобразование в набор отрезков. Общая задача ведет к упрощению контента изображения для отрисовки при помощи отрезков. То есть было какое-то сложное изображение с кучей кривых, а в результате получается изображение, состоящее только из прямых отрезков. Более примитивное и угловатое, но общую суть все еще отражает

Comment: Это как срисовывать картину руками, используя только лист в клеточку, линейку и карандаш

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm